# Export data from Rstudio to a new sheet in excisiting Excel file

Tags: r, excel

can you guys help me to solve this problem:
I want to export data into at new sheet in an already existing Excel file. Right now I have the following code:

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(ft, file = "GME.xlsx", sheetName = period, append = TRUE)
```

When I run this code it just created an Excel file, but I can't seem to make it add sheets when I run the code with other versions of the "ft" data frame

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use xlsx package for that. Could you try with below code ?

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(dataframe1, file="filename.xlsx", sheetName="sheet1")
write.xlsx(dataframe2, file="filename.xlsx", sheetName="sheet2", append=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I will try that. I was thinking about making a code that automatically added the new sheet. Do you now how to do that?

Comment: You can do with for loop I guess. For example : for (i in 1:9){
  write.xlsx(dataframe[i],"Excelfile.xlsx",sheet=paste0("sheet",i))
}

Comment: Can you maybe try at take a look at the code, and insert your loop, because I can't get it to work...

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add append=TRUE statement .
for (i in 1:9){ write.xlsx(dataframe[i],"Excelfile.xlsx",sheet=paste0("sheet",i),append=TRUE) }

Comment: Can't get it to work... Don't think i'm familiar enough with looping

Comment: I guess the problem is dataframe[i] and 1:9 numbers. How many dataframes do you have and can you do a list of these dataframes ?  for example I have three dataframes named ft,ft2,ft3. I created a list named df_list.  df_list=list(ft,ft2,ft3) and the loop is changed below : for (i in df_list){ write.xlsx(i,"Excelfile.xlsx",sheet=paste0("sheet",i),append=TRUE) }

Comment: I have tried to add my code in the question as a picture (couldnt set the code in in text form?). My idea was that when I run the code again in a couple of days, the tweets that I extract is in another time period, which I want to add to the Excel sheet in new sheet

Comment: Hi Emil, I saw your code, you don't need for loop for that. Your sheet name comes from period which will be changed when you run your code with different time period. Only if you want to control Excel file exist or not, you can add if/else statement for that. You can replace following code with your write.xlsx statement.  if (file.exists("GME.xlsx")){xlsx::write.xlsx(ft, file = "GME.xlsx", sheetName = period, append = TRUE)}else{ xlsx::write.xlsx(ft, file = "GME.xlsx", sheetName = period)}